# WPF IsEditable in ComboBox - how to remove autocomplete

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox and I would like to allow typing and to display in the TextBox only what was typed. so I used `IsEditable="True"`
The problem is that the autocompelete kicks in and completes the text to one of the items.

for example:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
     <ComboBoxItem>ABC</ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem>PPP</ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem>QQQ</ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem>NNN</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

When I type 'A' I get 'ABC' in the TextBox where the 'BC' is highlighted (and I would like to get only 'A')

Answer (score 10):

```
<ComboBox IsTextSearchEnabled="false" ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c1ComboBox1.AutoComplete = false;
```

or

```
<c1:C1ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="249" AutoComplete="False">
```

Comment: What is C1ComboBox? I'm looking for a solution without any added external code/dll

Comment: just add  the autocomplete = "false"  to ur <ComboBox IsEditable="True">

Comment: The problem is that there is no "autocomplete" property to the regular ComboBox

Comment: Answer seems to be for a control suite, not built in